# Angular module inside core module?

Tags: angular

need help with the structure of my project.
I follow a mix between:
https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7
and
https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-build-epic-angular-app-with-clean-architecture-91640ed1656

The 2 articles do not have the same exact structure for a scalable project.
For example, where is the best way to place an Alert Service containing components, service, model. (Used to display some alert on main or sub page).
I was thinking adding it under App-Core->Alert and put everything there, then import it in my core module definition then in the app root.
But someone tells me to add it under App->Modules, but this place is more for my lazy loading modules.
Not a good thing to add it under  App->Share
So it is a good place in my core module?

So I create the module under core folder. In the alert.module.ts I add declarations and exports for my component. Then in my core.module.ts I import the alert module. My core.module is already imported in the app.module.ts. But at the complication I got this error:

ERROR in HostResourceResolver: could not resolve alert.component.html in context of C:/data/_dev/Angular/KelvinAngular/src/app/core/alert/alert.component.ts)

anu idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a shared module, and put things like common functions like your alert (Component/Service) into the shared module.

You can import both CoreModule and SharedModule in your AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
imports: [
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
],
providers: [ CookieService ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

})

Comment: OK, but like the Alert component/service is use everywhere in the app and load one time only, is more like an singleton? So positionning it into Core module is more suitable?

Comment: In the 2 case, I can't find the correct way to add my AlertModule under an Share/Core module than in the AppModule. I got the error listed in the comment....

Comment: @Pierre-DSavard Share module could be used anywhere. What's the issue you do not like to put it into shared module?

Comment: Just because in one link the authors tell: The CoreModule should contain singleton services (which is usually the case), universal components and other features where there’s only once instance per application. But I do not have problem to put it undser Share to. But I still have the could not resolve alert.component.html. I will add some info of my module. Can you tell me waht I doing wrong?

Comment: Hoooo! I forgot to add the alert.component.html!! An I need to export the component in my share module too. Its working now

Comment: Happy to hear you solved the issue! Actually all services are singleton.